# Ubuntu 12.10 64bit ( fresh install ) usb modem ZTE 190S

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, usb-modem

I have installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 12.10 64-bit on samsung laptop (Model np350v5c-s0bae). The only problem I face is how to make the USB modem stick (Egypt Etisalat - ZTE MF190S) working.

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 19d2:2000 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM MF627/MF628/MF628+/MF636+ HSDPA/HSUPA
```

I have tried the stick modem on other machines and it is working properly.

Comment: Do you get any recommendations for a driver in Software sources > Additional drivers when the stick is plugged in?

Comment: no , nothing new in Additional Drivers

Answer (score 1):

I run `sudo apt-get install udev-discover` and restarted the system and it works.

Comment: this command removed some important programs without even asking .. restart and NOTHING would work